# Typed dataset not updating on column addition

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a datagridview that I'm using in Visual Studio 2008 for a winforms app. The datagridview is bound to a typed dataset. I added a few columns to the table referenced from the typed dataset. So, i open the typed dataset and reconfigured the datatable to show the new columns. When I do a preview, the columns are there. However, when i view the datagridview, there are no changes. I even rebound an no changes. I also tried creating a new table adapter and it doesn't even appear when selected sources for teh datagridview?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. The datagridview doesn't automatically accept changes that your datasource is configured to. If you add a column to your datasource, you need to configure your datagridview to display the new column.

Open properties to your datagridview and edit/add columns. It will allow you to add the new column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any DataSources Created under your Properties->Data Sources folder try removing them.